# The usage of uart_add_one_port in uart driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, uart

I am writing uart driver. My driver will support 4 instances and hence I passed `.nr = 4` while registering my uart with tty. When my probe function is called I need to do `uart_add_one_port` with the port specific structure.

I have a doubt here.Won't I need to call it 4 times since my driver will support 4 instances and since the base address for all of my uarts are different?

In most of the standard driver I have found irrespective of number of instances the driver supports,they are calling `uart_add_one_port` it only once.

Please explain why `uart_add_one_port` is needed and why it is called only in standard drivers.

Comment: It depends on how your hardware (device) is being enumerated in OS. This depends on the bus and corresponding bridge to that bus. See a lot of existing examples in *drivers/tty/serial/8250/*. You may consider to use `serdev` framework instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your hardware supports more than one uart port, You should call `uart_add_one_port` as per available ports.

Respectively devices will be registered like `/dev/ttyDEVX` name, Where `DEV` name of your driver, `X` is number of device.

[Refer similar driver like yours](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/max310x.c)